# In python is possible to call main method of other class from

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my programs 
1.post-commit.py
2.commit-comments.py

I need to call main method of commit-comments from post-commit.py with 5 arguements

Is that possible if so how can we do that

Thanks in advance
Sathishkumar

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as this in your post-commit.py script:

```
import commit_comments

commit_comments.main(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)
```

Comment: I just test run it with python commit-comments.py reps1015 exsy1002 admin artf1077 /opt/collabnet/teamforge/ test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "commit-comments.py", line 122, in <module> i gave six comments am i missing somewhere sshashank
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: main() takes exactly 6 arguments (0 given)

Comment: @user3264858, Yes, you need to pass your arguments in main.

Comment: sshashank,you can see am passing six arguments still it tells 0 given

Comment: @user3264858, not in your `main` you're not. Pass your arguments in `sys.exit(main(your 6 args))`

Comment: File "sathish.py", line 122
    sys.exit(main(reps1015 exsy1002 admin artf1077 /opt/collabnet/teamforge/ test))
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax it points at exsy1002 whats wrong in that

Comment: @user3264858, Your args must be separated with a `','`: `sys.exit(main(reps1015, exsy1002, admin, artf1077, /opt/collabnet/teamforge/, test))`